Decomposing the conjugation action into symmetric and antisymmetric parts
Consider a unitary representation $ \rho: G \to \mathrm{U}(n) $ corresponding to the action
$$
g \cdot v=gv
$$
We can define an action on the space of $ n \times n $ complex matrices by
$$
g \cdot M=gMg^\dagger
$$
The space of all matrices can be decomposed into the space of $ n \times n $ Hermitian matrices ( $ M^\dagger=M $ ) and the space of $ n \times n $ anti-Hermitian matrices ( $ M^\dagger=-M $ ). This is a decomposition as a direct sum of $ \mathbb{R}[G] $ submodules, but not as $ \mathbb{C}[G] $ submodules.
There is a similar decomposition of the space of all matrices into the space of symmetric matrices ( $ M^T=M $ ) and the space of $ n \times n $ anti-Hermitian matrices ( $ M^T=-M $ ). This decomposition has the advantage of being a direct sum of complex vector spaces, but the decomposition is not respected by the $ G $ action in general.
Suppose that the character of $ \rho $ is $ \chi $. Then the action on the space of all complex matrices should have the character $ \chi \overline{\chi} $ where the over bar denotes complex conjugate.
Constructing the character for the action of $ G $ on the subspace of Hermitian matrices and on the subspace of anti-Hermitian matrices seems a bit hard since these are real subrepresentations not complex subrepresentations so it all seems a bit dicy.
But what if $ \chi $ is real-valued? Then $ \chi \overline{\chi} =\chi^2 $ should decompose as
$$
\chi_S : g \longrightarrow \frac{1}{2}(\chi(g)^2 + \chi(g^2));
$$
$$
\chi_A : g \longrightarrow \frac{1}{2}(\chi(g)^2 - \chi(g^2)).
$$
what matrix subspaces do these two characters correspond to? I'm guessing that $ \chi_S $ corresponds to the symmetric matrices and $ \chi_A $ corresponds to the subspace of anti-symmetric matrices. But it is not obvious that either of these subspaces is really preserved by the conjugation action of $ G $ since $ (g \cdot M)^T=(gMg^\dagger)^T=(g^{\dagger})^T M^T g^T $. Indeed it is already clear that for irreps like $ \mathrm{SL}(2,3) \to \mathrm{U}(2) $ and $ \mathrm{SL}(2,5) \to \mathrm{U}(2) $ these characters do not just correspond to the symmetric and antisymmetric matrices.
Maybe to answer this question it will be helpful to consider another natural representation
$$
g \cdot M=gMg^T
$$
this is a group representation and for this action it is clear that the space of symmetric matrices is a $ \mathbb{C}[G] $ submodule and the space of antisymmetric matrices is a $ \mathbb{C}[G] $ submodule. I would assume that the subspace of symmetric matrices has the character $ \chi_S $ and the subspace of antisymmetric matrices has the character $ \chi_A $. Although again I am not entirely sure.

WLOG $G=\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{C})$, actually.
Let's handle the case $g\cdot A:=gAg^T$ first. We have $M_n(\mathbb{C})\cong\mathbb{C}^n\otimes\mathbb{C}^n$ via $uv^T\leftrightarrow u\otimes v$; this is an iso of complex $G$-reps. Writing $M=M_n(\mathbb{C})$ and $V=\mathbb{C}^n$, this means $\chi_M(g)=\chi_V(g)^2$.
The decomp $V^{\otimes 2}\cong S^2V\oplus\Lambda^2V$ corresponds in $M$ to the decomposition of matrices into symmetric and antisymmetric parts (wrt transpose), so characters are $\chi_{S^2V}$ and $\chi_{\Lambda^2V}$.

Now let's consider $g\cdot A:=gAg^\dagger$. We have $M\cong V\otimes V^\ast$ via $uv^\dagger\leftrightarrow u\otimes v$ as an iso of complex $G$-reps again, so the complex trace is $\chi_M(g)=|\chi_V(g)|^2$, which means the real trace is $2|\chi_V(g)|^2$.
Let $H\le M$ be the real subspace of Hermitian self-adjoint matrices. Observe $M=H\oplus iH$ is an orthogonal direct sum of real inner product spaces*, where $iH$ the subspace of Hermitian skew-adjoint matrices. Note $H\cong iH$ as real $G$-reps, via $A\leftrightarrow iA$, so $g$'s actions on $H$ and $iH$ have the same trace. This forces the real trace of $g$ acting on $H$ and $iH$ both to be $|\chi_V(g)|^2$.
We can arrive at this computationally, too. WLOG $g$ is diagonalizable (a trace formula valid on a dense subset of $G$ is valid on all of $G$ by continuity), indeed WLOG $g=\mathrm{diag}(\lambda_1,\cdots,\lambda)$. A real orthogonal basis for $H$ is
$$\big\{\, e_j e_j^\dagger,
~\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(e_je_k^\dagger+e_ke_j^\dagger),
~\tfrac{i}{\sqrt{2}}(e_je_k^\dagger-e_ke_j^\dagger)\,\big\}.$$
The diagonal matrices $e_je_j^\dagger$ are eigenvectors with eigenvalues $|\lambda_j|^2$, and the 2D planes spanned by appropriate pairs of the latter two kinds of basis elements listed above are acted on by $g$ just as $\mathbb{C}$ is acted upon by multiplication-by-the-scalar-$\lambda_i\overline{\lambda_j}$, so the real trace is
$$ \sum_j |\lambda_j|^2+\sum_{j<k}2\mathrm{Re}(\lambda_j\overline{\lambda_k})=\Bigl|\sum_j \lambda_j\Bigr|^2=|\chi_V(g)|^2. $$
*As $U(n)$-reps, we can further decompose $H=\mathbb{R}I\oplus H'$ with $H'$ of tracefree Hermitian matrices, corresponding to $iH=\mathfrak{u}(n)=\mathfrak{u}(1)I\oplus\mathfrak{su}(n)$.
